# Airflow command not working after installation

Tags: installation, airflow

I am new to Airflow. I installed the airflow in Python 3.6.8 using the command:

```
pip install \
 apache-airflow==1.10.12 \
 --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-1.10.12/constraints-3.7.txt"
```

The setup was complete with no error. However when I run the 'airflow' command, it shows the error like:

```
File "/Users/a13220361/airflow_final/bin/airflow", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('apache-airflow==1.10.12', 'airflow')
  File "/Users/a13220361/airflow_final/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 664, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/Users/a13220361/airflow_final/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1435, in run_script
    .format(**locals()),
pkg_resources.ResolutionError: Script 'scripts/airflow' not found in metadata at '/Users/a13220361/airflow_final/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_airflow-1.10.12.dist-info'
```

I cannot understand what this error is. Please help.

Comment: Try it in a virtualenv and see.

Comment: I am running a virtualenv already, still no result. What is this error actually?

Comment: juste pip install apache-airflow should work no ?

Comment: Not helped that also